# Generating new Opera user profile

Tags: windows, opera, user-profiles

How can I create new user profile for Opera?

I like to keep lot of open tabs, but often when I work I need to look up things every now and then.  So when I need to concentrate on something, e.g. some important TO-DO-NOW, the other tabs can distract me.  The best approach for me so far was to create a whole new profile and close the default one.

With *nix version of Opera, I'd can simply `opera -pd ~/todo/urgent` and Opera would automatically create all files and things it needs.

But on Windows, `opera.exe /Settings d:\todo\urgent\` brings an error:

```
Error initializing Opera: module 9 (prefs)
```

Description of this switch on Opera's [official site](http://www.opera.com/docs/switches/#win-only) says:

> **/Settings <full path>**       Launch with specified settings (opera6.ini) file

so probably the .ini file is missing.  Maybe I could "steal" it from somewhere, but it seems to contain quite a lot of full paths to edit, settings that I don't want to use, etc.

Is there any clean and easy way to generate new instance of user settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not on Windows, so I can't try if it works, but according to [this blog post](http://my.opera.com/ruario/blog/2011/09/28/the-pd-personal-directory-switch) -pd should work on Windows too.

Comment: I just wish I had known it before I blasted my old profile :/ They should definitely be more clear about it at the [help page](http://www.opera.com/docs/switches/#win-only)

Comment: I have just filed a bug report to Opera, with suggestion that this switch should be added to their official help.

Comment: Checking back ages later, I can see they have added `-pd` to the official help. (Can't see if it was due to my report or not...)

Comment: @AloisMahdal: according to my experience with Opera, I guess it wasn't due to your report :)